# C# Windows forms app. Override toString question

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is it possible to give the Override ToString method the return value of another method?
So in the screenshot you will see a override tostring, which displays the Radius * the PI value.

And I want to say:

Radius * PI value = return value

(return value = "oppervlakte")

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work, call the function in the ToString method and insert it's value into the interpolated string.

```cs
public override float BerekenOppervlakte()
{
    float oppervlakte = (float)(Radius * Pi);
    return oppervlakte; 
}

public override string ToString()
{
    var oppervlakte = BerekenOppervlakte();
    return $"{Radius}m x {Pi} = {oppervlakte}";
}
```

Comment: It's a method call, so change `{oppervlakte}` to `{oppervlakte()}`.

Comment: Ah...gotcha!  I was thinking, why even have that line? Just do: `return $"{Radius}m x {Pi} = {BerekenOppervlakte()}";`